# ReadByte from USB port in C#

Tags: c#, usb, port

I would like to ask why does my program ReadByte() function returns a different value. My USB port will be sending a byte value of 8, however, when the c# program reads it, it receives a value of 56. Why is that happening? The c# code is as below:

```
private void serial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
            port.Open();

            int num1 = 0;
            num1 = port.ReadByte();
            String a = Convert.ToString(num1);
            MessageBox.Show(a);
            port.Close();
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should try a packet sniffer to debug what the device is actually sending. Try Message analyzer from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn741264(v=vs.85).aspx 
I can see that both 56 and 8 end with binary 1000 but I can not tell much without actually debugging the sent message from the USB drive.

Answer (score 3):

You may be sending ascii instead of binary data. 56 is ascii for "8".